# Can the kernel be moved to a different mtd while the system is running?

Tags: kernel, arm

I am attempting to do a full update on a mobile `Linux Arm` device. I have successfully pivoted my file system root and have been able to flash a new file system to that mtd. What I would like to accomplish now is something similar for the kernel.

I am wondering if it is possible to perhaps pivot the kernel to another mtd or even perhaps the RAM. Or maybe there is some other method I am overlooking?

Any insight to avenues I could use would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: At least on x86, the kernel is loaded from disk into RAM, and then runs from RAM—overwriting the file (or partition) won't do anything to the running kernel.

Comment: @derobert any idea what I should be looking for to find out where my kernel runs from?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "it runs from RAM". You'd have to check the bootloader to see which partition its stored on..

Comment: @derobert: well, there is XIP (eXecute In Place), which allows running code without moving it to RAM. But it's typically only used on systems with very little RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel runs from RAM. It is impossible to swap out kernel code or data. Linux itself never accesses the file containing the kernel (except as part of system updates). Indeed on some embedded systems the kernel might not be accessible to the OS at all but instead located in a place where the bootloader can find it. Some kernel mode code is loaded from module files, but after a module is loaded the file it comes from doesn't matter.

Thus you can do whatever you like with the kernel file. Just make sure that the bootloader can still find it afterwards.